# Extracting lines between two lines starting with "$" with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a big text file with some data in it which looks like this:

```
$  10c20
data
data
.
.
data
data
$  10c21
data
data
.
.
data
data
$  10c22
.
.
```

I want to extract data between each two commented lines (starts with "$") and store that chunk of data in a new file and then the next chunk till the end of file. I tried "sed" but I was unable to obtain what I needed. any idea?

desired output:

```
$  10c20
    data
    data
    .
    .
    data
    data
```

and

```
$  10c21
    data
    data
    .
    .
    data
    data
```

and

```
$  10c22
    data
    data
    .
    .
    data
    data
```

and ...

Comment: It's hard/impossible to use sed for multiline operations. At most two lines in a row is what I 'easily' manage to work. Is any language a possibility?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question, too.

Comment: @kabanus I've already done something like that with only two lines with different patterns, but I dont know how to do this one

Comment: Calculation, that could mean that awk is the "right" tool. Please give more details about your requirements. At the moment it looks like "lets remove lines with `$`".

Comment: @LarsFischer so would you please show me how to do it with awk?

Comment: What is the "calculation"?

Comment: I just noticed [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/multiline-pattern-match-using-sed-awk-or-grep#10250) is similar, not sure if it's a duplicate.

Comment: @LarsFischer , I will paste each extracted block into a file which is the input of another computational program (finite element computations)

Comment: @kabanus , the different is that I have the same character in the beginning of commented lines

Comment: That's a vital piece of info! Add that to your question, and elaborate on how you tell the difference between a comment and a title.

Comment: @kabanus , between comment and title?! I've never mentioned "title"!

Comment: Why did you say this :"the different is that I have the same character in the beginning of commented lines"? I understood you fine the first time.In any case it seems [what you asked and what you want are two different things](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). If you'll edit I'll help, otherwise I'm having a bit of trouble.

Comment: @kabanus , I meant the different between the link you have provided and what I asked. why should I edit my question?! it is so clear, or maybe you could tell me how should I ask this, I appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a 'higher' language like Python/Perl there's a common built-in `csplit`, though you need to agree to work with files:

```
/home/.../RGS/tmp>csplit bla  '/^\$/' {*} 
0
21
21
21
21
/home/.../RGS/tmp>cat xx00
/home/.../RGS/tmp>cat xx01
$  10c20
data1
data1
/home/.../RGS/tmp>cat xx02
$  10c21
data2
data2
/home/.../RGS/tmp>cat xx03
$  10c22
data3
data3
/home/.../RGS/tmp>cat xx04
$  10c23
data4
data4
/home/.../RGS/tmp>
```

where bla is:

```
$  10c20
data1
data1
$  10c21
data2
data2
$  10c22
data3
data3
$  10c23
data4
data4
```

and at the end just `rm xx*`.

**EDIT**

Once the files are ready, in bash just:

```
for inp in xx*; do
     cat $inp | toSomeComputations &
     #Or
     toSomeComputations $inp &
 done
```

of course, you can use something else to make this loop parallel.

Comment: I think that you didn't understand what I wanted, the data between two commented lines are variable and huge, cant use your code. thanks anyway

Comment: This works on 'variable and huge' data, but maybe you should consider using a script in an easier language anyway. If you're unclear how to process the files after the split I'll edit.

Comment: it is a massive parallel computational program, so it doesn't help, I just want to paste the extracted block into another file as input to mentioned program.

Comment: What piece is parallel? Why are you using Linux commands for this? You need to write all this stuff in the question, not post mortem on answers. Re-write the question with the entire flow please. It's easy to loop these files and cat/give them to another process...

Comment: I never said that I want to use bash for parallel computations! I just said that I want to copy and paste the extracted data blocks to another file which is input for another program. ***And the latter will do the parallel computations without knowing of how the input has made***! I just answered Lars question about computations

Comment: @gnome Sorry for the aggravation, I tried an edit to make myself more clear, but if that isn't then I hope someone else can better help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **GNU** awk script, that reproduces @kabanus answer. I dont know how this helps you when the answer given by @kabanus was not working for you, but here it is.

**script.awk**

```
function doit( header ) { 
    # filename with leading zeros in number
    outFileName = sprintf("out_%04d", NR-1)
    printf("%s%s", header, $0 ) > outFileName
    # now lets run a command on that file, e.g. cat
    system("cat " outFileName )
}

# set record split by the dollar lines
BEGIN   { RS="[$][^\n]+" }

{ 
  # on NR == 1 ( the first record ) oldRT is empty
  # we need to store RT and use oldRT when we output $0 
  # for the next record
  if( oldRT ) doit( oldRT )
  oldRT = RT
}
```

Run it like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`

Comment: how can I print out each extracted chunk of data to separate files? (considering for loop)

Comment: Moment please, I was away from keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
awk '
function doCalculation() {
    # do whatever you want with the multi-line string "buf" then
    printf "%s", buf
    buf = ""
}
/^\$/ { doCalculation() }
{ buf = buf $0 ORS }
END { doCalculation() }
' file
```

You can make buf an array instead of a multi-line string if that's more convenient but the logics the same either way.